# Cannot launch phantomjs with selenium webdriver

Tags: python, macos, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I'm getting an error in launching phantomjs with selenium webdriver on a mac. 
This is my call to launch phantomjs:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/phantomjs')
```

I get the following error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/webdriver.py", line 50, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/service.py", line 75, in start
    raise WebDriverException("Unable to start phantomjs with ghostdriver.", e)
```

WebDriverException: Message: Unable to start phantomjs with ghostdriver.
Screenshot: available via screen

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?